# Bold text in strings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a `DataTable` with columns `typeof(string)`. I am adding strings to this table and I need to have some of text in bold. My string looks like that:

```
row["UserData"] = user.Name + "\n" + user.Description + "\n" + user.Number + "\t" + user.Date;
```

Is it possible to make `user.Name` in this code bold?

I am using .NET 4.0 and WPF.

Comment: No, you need to use a RichTextBox for complex formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are just text, if you want to format text you have multiple ways of doing so but i do not know of anything "native". e.g. use XML markup around `user.Name` to encode the formatting as text, that then can be used by some control which displays it to adjust the rendering.

Answer (score 3):

DataTable is just a data store - it doesn't control the display of the data.  When you bind a ListView or other WPF control to the DataTable, you can style the columns of the control to display one of the columns text in bold.

Answer (score 2):

Bolding text in DataGrid using DataGridRow: [WPF DataGrid Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples)

```
<Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12"
                        Fill="Red" Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="4,0,0,0"
                        Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Text="!"
                        ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                 FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGridRow}},
                                 Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This [link](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx) also shows how to bold a StackPanel TextBlock.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99% sure you can only style columns of a DataTable, not the data within them.

Answer (score 1):

Where is this being shown?

Is this a plain text concatenated string you are trying to make bold, is it HTML, or are you wanting the user.Name portion of the code in the IDE to display as bold?

If it's plain text, there isn't much you can do.  Displaying the string in some email clients will show as bold if you surround it with asterisks (*).

For HTML, you can surround the user.Name with either CSS or a strong/bold tag:

```
row["UserData"] = "<strong>" + user.Name + </strong>" + "\n" + user.Description + "\n" + user.Number + "\t"  + user.Date;
```

or

```
row["UserData"] = "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>" + user.Name + "</span>" + "\n" + user.Description + "\n" + user.Number + "\t" + user.Date;
```

Comment: I am displaying it in user interface of my WPF application. My strings are defined in xaml.cs file. I want only part of this string to be  bold - this with name.